# Change image Javascript

Tags: javascript, image

This is the part i want to change

```
img alt="image" class="background-image" src="X.jpg">
```

X should be replaced by

normal.jpg or mobile.jpg based on

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
            || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
        )
```

so if this is true i want to have there the mobile jpg else the normal, i tried

```
var image = document.getElementByClass('background-image');
            image.style.backgroundImage = 'url(mobile.jpg)';
```

with no success

Comment: `getElementByClass` isn't a thing. Look into `getElementsByClassName`

Comment: @j08691 Neither is `getElementByClassName`, but `getElementsByClassName` will get you places.

Comment: @Shomz - yup, typo fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)** that return array of objects and select the first one using `[0]` :

```
if( condition )
    document.getElementsByClassName('background-image')[0].src = 'mobile.jpg';
else 
    document.getElementsByClassName('background-image')[0].src = 'normal.jpg';
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

I'd do something like this:

```
if (window.innerWidth <= 524) {
    getElementById('background-image').style.backgroundImage = "url('mobile.jpg')";
}
```

`getElementByClass` returns an array so you'll need to get the first element if you want to use it `var image = document.getElementsByClassName('background-image')[0]`

Comment: It's actually getElementsByClassName()